# clf.pred_proba used for Histogram Oriented Gradient predictions

Tags: scikit-learn, histogram-of-oriented-gradients

I wrote this code several years ago.  I am revisiting it only to find that some things have since changed in the useage of some statement.   The code examines 99 images of Trucks, SUVs, and Sedans by converting them into histogram oriented gradients.  It then uses sklearn to create a SVM using

```
clf.svm.SVC(kernal='linear', probability=True)
clf.fit(feature,targets)
```

where the feature is the HOG images and targets is the vehicle type i.e., TRK, SED, SUV

Everything appears to run to this point.

I then submit another image (not in the training set) to the SVM to test the model I use these statements

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])

Predfile='XXXX.prd.png'
grayscale = rgb2gray(img)
fdPred = hog(grayscale, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(6, 6),cells_per_block=(3, 3), visualize=False)
prob=clf.predict_proba(fdPred)
```

This this point I get the following error

```
File "C:\Users\thiir\.conda\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 670, in _predict_proba
        X = self._validate_for_predict(X)

  File "C:\Users\thiir\.conda\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 475, in _validate_for_predict
    order="C", accept_large_sparse=False)

  File "C:\Users\thiir\.conda\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\thiir\.conda\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 698, in check_array
    "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Any insights?

Comment: The error message has the enough information, I guess. You need to reshape your input when your data has a single feature. Try `[fdPred]`.

Comment: changing the statement from: prob=clf.predict_prob(fdPred) to prob=clf.predict_prob([fdPred])  fixed the problem.  Thank you.  can you help me understand what this change does?

Comment: It converts your single data point into a 2D data.

Comment: nice.. Thank you